# Error "no global: `self` or `global` found" running ember-template-compiler in grunt

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs, grunt-ember-templates

Trying to upgrade an Ember project to version 2, still using Grunt as the build tool, getting this error after adding ember-template compiler task:

"Running "emberTemplates:dist" (emberTemplates) task

> > Error: ember-template-compiler.js:869
> >           throw new Error('no global: `self` or `global` found');
> >                 ^
> >     no global: `self` or `global` found
> >     Warning: Ember Handlebars failed to compile..."

```
bower.json:
{
  "name": "frb-ember",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "2.0.1",
    "ember-data": "2.0",
    "handlebars": "2.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "3.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "latest",
    "moment": "~2.9.0",
    "d3": "latest"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "ember": ">= 1.13.0 < 2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ember-mocha-adapter": "0.2.1"
  }
}
```

/////

```
package.json
{
  "name": "frb-ember",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^3.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "connect-livereload": "~0.2.0",
    "ember-data": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "ember-template-compiler": "~1.9.0-alpha",
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.8.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.3",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-ember-templates": "*",
    "grunt-include-bootstrap": "^0.1.1",
    "grunt-mocha": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-neuter": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-open": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-replace": "~0.4.4",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^2.1.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "~0.1.3",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.1.0",
    "time-grunt": "~0.1.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  }
}
```

/////

```
Gruntfile.js

// Generated on 2015-03-03 using generator-ember 0.8.6
'use strict';
var LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35730;
var lrSnippet = require('connect-livereload')({
    port: LIVERELOAD_PORT
});
var mountFolder = function(connect, dir) {
    return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // show elapsed time at the end
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);
    // load all grunt tasks
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // configurable paths
    var yeomanConfig = {
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
    };

    grunt.initConfig({
        yeoman: yeomanConfig,
        watch: {
            emberTemplates: {
                files: '<%= yeoman.app %>/templates/**/*.hbs',
                tasks: ['emberTemplates']
            },
            compass: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:server']
            },
            neuter: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['neuter']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
                },
                files: [
                    '.tmp/scripts/*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/img/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ]
            }
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: process.env.PORT || 8000,
                // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: process.env.IP || 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function(connect) {
                        return [
                            lrSnippet,
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function(connect) {
                        return [
                            mountFolder(connect, 'test'),
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp')
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function(connect) {
                        return [
                            mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.dist)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        open: {
            server: {
                path: 'http://<%= connect.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.options.port %>'
            }
        },
        include_bootstrap: {
            files: {
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles.css': '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/less/manifest.less',
            },
        },
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
                'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },
        mocha: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    run: true,
                    urls: ['http://<%= connect.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.options.port %>/index.html']
                }
            }
        },
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
                generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/img/generated',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/img',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
                importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
                httpImagesPath: '/img',
                httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/img/generated',
                httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
                relativeAssets: false
            },
            dist: {},
            server: {
                options: {
                    debugInfo: false
                }
            }
        },
        // not used since Uglify task does concat,
        // but still available if needed
        /*concat: {
            dist: {}
        },*/
        // not enabled since usemin task does concat and uglify
        // check index.html to edit your build targets
        // enable this task if you prefer defining your build targets here
        /*uglify: {
            dist: {}
        },*/
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/img/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        useminPrepare: {
            html: '.tmp/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }
        },
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/**/*.js'],
            options: {
                dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts'],
                assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts'],
                patterns: {
                    js: [
                        [/["']([^:"']+\.(?:png|gif|jpe?g))["']/img, 'Image replacement in js files']
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/img',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/img'
                }]
            }
        },
        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/img',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/img'
                }]
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
                        '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                    //collapseWhitespace: true,
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true*/
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    src: '*.html',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },
        replace: {
            app: {
                options: {
                    variables: {
                        ember: 'bower_components/ember/ember.js',
                        ember_data: 'bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.js'
                    }
                },
                files: [{
                    src: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
                    dest: '.tmp/index.html'
                }]
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    variables: {
                        ember: 'bower_components/ember/ember.prod.js',
                        ember_data: 'bower_components/ember-data/ember-data.prod.js'
                    }
                },
                files: [{
                    src: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
                    dest: '.tmp/index.html'
                }]
            }
        },
        // Put files not handled in other tasks here
        copy: {
            fonts: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    flatten: true,
                    filter: 'isFile',
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts/',
                    src: [
                        'bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/**'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'img/**/*.{webp,gif,ico,png}',
                        'styles/fonts/**/*'
                    ]
                }]
            }
        },
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'emberTemplates',
                'compass:server'
            ],
            test: [
                'emberTemplates',
                'compass'
            ],
            dist: [
                'emberTemplates',
                'compass:dist',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin',
                'htmlmin'
            ]
        },
        emberTemplates: {
            options: {
                templateCompilerPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js',
                handlebarsPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js',
                templateNamespace: 'HTMLBars',
                templateName: function(sourceFile) {
                    var templatePath = yeomanConfig.app + '/templates/';
                    return sourceFile.replace(templatePath, '');
                }
            },
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '.tmp/scripts/compiled-templates.js': '<%= yeoman.app %>/templates/**/*.hbs'
                }
            }
        },
        neuter: {
            app: {
                options: {
                    filepathTransform: function(filepath) {
                        return yeomanConfig.app + '/' + filepath;
                    }
                },
                src: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/app.js',
                dest: '.tmp/scripts/combined-scripts.js'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function(target) {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('serve', function(target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'open', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'replace:app',
            'concurrent:server',
            'neuter:app',
            'copy:fonts',
            'connect:livereload',
            'open',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:server',
        'replace:app',
        'concurrent:test',
        'connect:test',
        'neuter:app',
        'mocha'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'replace:dist',
        'include_bootstrap',
        'useminPrepare',
        'emberTemplates',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'neuter:app',
        'concat',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'copy',
        'rev',
        'usemin'
    ]);

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ember-templates');

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'jshint',
        'test',
        'emberTemplates',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I had a similar issue with a tool we used and we just added a variable global and set it to this before ember template compiler.  Total hack, but I was feeling lazy

Comment: Additionally that version of ember is not compatible with that version of ember template compiler, and handlebars is no longer used

Comment: Just ran into this. [This fork of grunt-ember-templates has a fix.](https://github.com/huguesdk/grunt-ember-templates/commit/204c9c12a613180be3c35f80c9b701a69ee10342)